# memory consumption when creating objects Java

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, nio, cpu-usage

I'm not familiar with the whole subject, so I'd like to ask you a few questions.

I have a functionality in my program where I search the filesystem for certain folders that match a regex.That means, I want to search in a certain folder, all subfolders, to which a certain regex matches. Additionally, I don't want to search in certain subfolders that have a certain subfolder with a certain file, so I want to exclude the search in these subfolders. To be more precise, when I search in folder X, I want to exclude from the search all subfolders of X that have a specific subfolder (`Person`) and contain a specific file (`personality.xml`) in it.

Therefore I have used this "as efficient as possible" feature of java.nio: `Files.walkFileTree`.

Here is my implementation:

```
        List<Path> paths = new ArrayList<>();
        String regex = "myRegex";
        Files.walkFileTree(Paths.get("myPathWhereIWantSearchAllSubfoldesr")), new SimpleFileVisitor<>(){

            @Override
            public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                if(Files.isHidden(dir)){
                    return FileVisitResult.SKIP_SUBTREE;
                }

                if(dir.toFile().getName().contains(regex)){
                    paths.add(dir);
                }

                if(Files.exists(Paths.get(String.valueOf(dir), "Config", "ComponentConfig.xml"))){
                    return FileVisitResult.SKIP_SUBTREE;
                }

                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }               
        });
```

Now my questions:

If I create a path for every folder all the time and see if it exists, isn't there some kind of permanent objects created that use up memory in some way? If so, what kind of memory do they consume? Is there any way to clean these objects so that they don't fill up memory or any garbage during the search? Because during the search anyway, I think the CPU will be heavily used, if I apply my search to a huge folder, I want to avoid any overhead in terms of memory consumption or CPU usage.

I am very grateful for any advice, hint or comment.

Answer (score 1):

Java is open source, so you can lookup the source for `Files.walkFileTree`. Exactly how depends on your IDE, in Eclipse just hit F3. Looking at the source one can see the the Event object, which contains the Path, is discarded immediately after calling your visitor. To be precise, I was looking at Java 11.